# "odds" in the song of Ed Sheeran

Tags: meaning-in-context

I've just listened to [the song "perfect"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iKzRIweSBLA) by Edd Sheeran, and in one of the sentences [he says](https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/edsheeran/perfect.html):

> We are still kids, but we're so in love
>
> Fighting against all **odds**
>
> I know we'll be alright this time
>
> Darling, just hold my hand

What is the meaning of word "odd" in this context?

For me, by the context the meaning should be a noun but by the checking [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/odd) as well as the [Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/odd) I didn't find any meaning of noun for this word. Then what should it be?

Comment: Try looking up "odds" instead of "odd". Once you get the definition you'll have your answer, so the question is off topic for ELL.

Comment: Just look for "*against all odds*". Even Phil Collins has a song with this phrase in the title.

Answer (score 2):

"Against all odds" is a standard phrase for an unlikely event. There was a 1980's movie of that title, which as @SovereignSun noted had a Phil Collins title song, which won an Oscar nomination.

To me, Ed Sheeran's lyric isn't the best example of the usage. I think Phil Collins lyrics flow more naturally: "And you coming back to me is against all odds/ It's the chance I've got to take".